# Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined using BaseView in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I create a `BaseView.js` :

```
 define(["jquery" ,
         "underscore" ,
         "backbone" ,
        ],function($ , _ , Backbone){
    var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
       initialize: function () {
           console.log("calling public method here");
       }
    });
 });
```

Then I have another view :

```
define(["jquery" ,
        "underscore" ,
        "backbone" ,
        "views/BaseView"
       ],function($ , _ , Backbone , BaseView){

      var ChildView = BaseView.extend({
          initialize: function() {
             BaseView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
          }
      });
      return ChildView;
});
```

I got an error in my console `Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined`.

Any idea what could be causing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you have to return BaseView in the first file (BaseView.js)?

Answer (score 1):

Make the function at BaseView.js return BaseView